# What is the data version that is read when using the follower read option?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

If you set `yb_read_from_followers=on` and are connected to a tablet leader, do you still read stale data from a snapshot `yb_follower_read_staleness_ms` ago?

I read this: https://dev.to/franckpachot/read-from-the-nearest-peer-in-a-multi-region-database-with-followers-read-59d9 and the author makes it seem like you're always reading from a snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follower reads, enabled using `yb_read_from_followers`, reads data that is consistent with `yb_follower_read_staleness_ms` milliseconds old.
In order to enable follower reads, `yb_read_from_followers` must set to `on`, and a transaction must be explicitly marked as readonly.

The tablet chosen can be both a leader or a follower, the tablet is chosen based on being closest, where closest is determined by the placement of the tablet.
If the reader cannot obtain data that is consistent with `yb_follower_read_staleness_ms`, it will go to the leader and obtain the data. The leader is current and therefore must always be able to provide the requested data.